# NSView will not receive mouseDown

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, desktop-application

My custom NSView is currently ignoring my attempt at handling `mouseDown` events...

```
class MainButton: NSView {

    override func acceptsFirstMouse(theEvent: NSEvent!) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent!) {
        let alert = NSAlert()
        alert.messageText = "Testing..."
        alert.runModal()
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)

        // more custom drawing
    }
}
```

Is there an obvious reason the `mouseDown` function here would not be triggered when clicking on the drawn view?

Additionally, I can confirm that `acceptsFirstMouse` is never called.

Comment: Are you sure that your MainButton is in your view hierarchy at all?  I mean, can you see the results of "more custom drawing"?  Is it possible that there are other views overlapping your button?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm in the same boat.